# is it reasonable to get rid of .application file from VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, console-application, exe, release, publish

when build solution, the file  app.application file gets generated, is there any reason to have this file?

I am using VS2012 for a console application running on windows box, I am thinking to just generate .exe files without build installer files, etc. Now if I can go to my bin/release folder I can see this .application file which I don't think I saw it in the earlier version of Visual studio, do I need this file for any reason or I should just get rid of it, but I couldn't find anywhere to disable this from being generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the solution is go to project property and Security tab, uncheck Enable ClickOne security settings, then the file won't be generated.